# SVN Remote Merging

Tags: svn, svn-merge

I currently have a traditional SVN `trunk/tags/branches` configuration, but only `trunk` is actually being used.

I'd like to add a `release` location, so I have `trunk/tags/branches/release`, which I can then track with Jenkins to perform builds.  When trunk is tested and "releasable", I'd like to overwrite the `release` location with the contents of `trunk`.

Ideally this would be possible remotely i.e. without having to checkout `release` to a developers PC.

Is this possible?  I've done:

`svn copy http://.../trunk http://.../release`

And then made and commited some changes to trunk.  But then attempting to do:

`svn merge http://.../trunk http://...release`

returns:

`svn: E195020: Cannot merge into mixed-revision working copy [40249:40256]; try updating first`

Is what I'm trying to do possible?!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not possible.  You *must* merge onto a working copy, and then commit that.

The [usage notes for `merge`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) shows that all possible invocations take a working copy path as the target.  It will always fail if you pass in a repository URL.